# Is there a way to find out which actions constitute a cache hit or miss?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I am trying to gain insights into which actions constitute a cache hit or miss during a bazel build. Not only that, but also whether they are "remote cache hit", "local", "remote" and so on. In the bazel event protocol (BEP), I can see a total summary of all actions in the section buildMetrics.runnerCount, e.g. (some dummy data below)

```
`"runnerCount":[
  {"name": "total", "count":263406},
  {"name": "remote cache hit", "count":158034},
  {"name": "internal", "count":104827},
  {"name": "local", "count":40},
  {"name": "remote", "count":2}
]`
```

however, I'd like to know exactly which actions constitute a remote cache hit or a local cache hit for example. The build event protocol doesn't seem to provide this information.

The execution log, instead, produced by using --execution_log_json_file reports for every action what is the 'runner', hence I can see exactly the info I need. The problem with that is that the execution log for big builds can amount to 100+ GB and makes build time very slow (whereas the very reason I want to find out about cache hits or misses is to speed up debugging and build time, so this seems counter-intuitive)

I know of tools such as BuildBuddy which provide information about cache hits or misses just using the build event stream. I am steering away from using these tools at the moment. Hence, I am assuming there must be a way to retrieve this information without having to use the execution log?

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to retrieve whether each action constitutes a hit or miss and what is the spawn type using ONLY the build event protocol?
2. If not, is the only alternative to get this information to use --execution_log_[binary/json]_file instead? How do tools such as buildBuddy retrieve this data then?
3. If the execution log is the only way, is it possible to stream it in a similar way to how build events are streamed using bes_backend?

Comment: [--noexecution_log_sort](https://bazel.build/reference/command-line-reference#flag--execution_log_sort) makes the execution log less painful. Also the protobuf format should be more compact and faster to parse than JSON. But it's still slow, and then you have to deal with parsing the massive file.